# A problem with the Spring MVC and Spring Security configuration

Tags: java, spring

I'm doing a Web application project in Java and I have a problem with securing the application using Spring Security, namely my configuration does not work, I've tried several ways to configure Spring Security, but it does not protect the application.
  I bow to whoever will help me with this confi guration. Below are dependencies and a configuration class. I am asking for forgiveness, I am a beginner programmer. Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi,Firstly go through this-https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question ,secondly please explain your issue ,may be share some code and errors you are getting ,thanks

Comment: Please include code as text in the question body (indented by four spaces so that it appears as code formatting), rather than an image. This makes the code easier to read, especially for users who have poor vision and have an assistive technology such as an alternate font or screen reader.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is that I have an MVC and Security configuration, but the Secuity configuration does not work at all, no errors in the console. Stamping url addresses does not work. I am sorry for the organization I am a new user.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/find").denyAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin().and().httpBasic();

}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    super.configure(auth);

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}
```

}

```
 <!--Spring Security-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: So, the problem is that when I run the application and hit any url (even "/ find"), none is blocked, only goes on. I have a problem in this.

Comment: Don't add additional information as an answer, instead edit your question and add the information in there.